# Adjust Auto-Layout inside UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

So I am creating a forum. When a post includes an image I would like to keep the aspect ratio of the downloaded image while making the image's width constant at 75% of the cell's width.

I created an outlet for the imageHeightConstraint in my custom cell class and tried the code below in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
let newHeight = (image!.size.height/image!.size.width)*cell.uploadedImageView.frame.width
 cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight//Calculate the new height
```

The code above doesn't adjust the image size at all.

Currently I have the constraint for image width to be 75% of cell's width and height equal 200.

I also already have all the code to adjust the tableviewcell automatically depending on content and that is working fine.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if let image = image {
    cell.image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:cell.image.widthAnchor, multiplier: image.size.height/image.size.width).isActive = true
}
```

If you want to also limit the height to 200, then you can also add

```
cell.image.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant:200).isActive=true
```